# Encryption after decryption

Tags: terminal, encryption, openssl

I have a file encrypted.
I want to get the content of the encrypted file  and after that I want to encrypt the file with a new key.

```
openssl Type-of-Encryption-used -d -k "key of decription" in- file-encripted
```

The output is content of the file.

I want to encrypt the file with a new key every time it is decrypted. Every time I decrypt the file for get the content the file will be encrypted with a new key. How i can do it?